# Client-Side Editing of HTML Webpage

Tags: html, web, client

I'm not sure where to put this so I put this post in StackOverFlow since it is related to programming. Anyways, the website is done and I want my client to be able to edit the pages without learning HTML all at once. 
I want s/he to be able to change the text without learning HTML on a website or programme. Is this possible, if so please, please, help me. Is there already a project that can help do this? Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: This is not the site for such a broad question.

Comment: search for `contenteditable` attribute and `Mutation events`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text on the site to be editible, usually the site is built on a backend suited for editing such as Joomla or Wordpress.

If you want to do it from scratch, you'd have to have a database containing all of the text elements you want them to be able to edit, then use PHP to echo the text into the page.

That way, you could make a simple interface to edit the text in the database which would, in turn, edit the text on the site.

Example:

Index Page

```
<div id="description"><?php echo $description;></div>
```

Update Page

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $description;?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

If that example is hooked into a database with the above explained table, they can just edit the text in a box to update the site.